# How can I end all unneccesary processes except cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to end all processes **except** cmd.exe, so that the script can remove files without any processes interfering. I have tried using

```
taskkill /f /fi "IMAGENAME ne cmd.exe"
```

but this doesn't work. As expected it kills all processes but it still ends up killing cmd.exe. Is this because it is killing a process that keeps windows open? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely cause is that you're also killing the parent process for cmd.exe, which then kills all of its child processes.

What is it you're actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You can do this with the Windows start menu.

Comment: I want to keep this automated, Dany.

Answer (score 1):

End all processes except for these:

```
spoolsv.exe
lsass.exe
csrss.exe
smss.exe
winlogon.exe
svchost.exe
services.exe
conhost.exe
cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing as far as I can see - but if your goal is indeed to prevent unauthorised use, why not simply execute `shutdown` ? - see `shutdown /?` from the prompt for options.